# Adjusting number precision in matplotlib basemap colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

[image]

In the map above, I would like to adjust the colorbar labels so that they have a maximum of 3 places after the decimal. Here is what I am doing right now:

```
kwargs = {'fmt': '%.1f'}
cb = m.colorbar(cs, "bottom", size="3%", pad='2%', extend='neither', drawedges=False,
                norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=xaxis_min, vmax=xaxis_max), spacing='proportional', **kwargs)
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\r\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 895, in __init__
    ColorbarBase.__init__(self, ax, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fmt'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the [`Colorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.ColorbarBase) constructor, you will see that you need to specify the format using the kwarg `format`. Instead you have tried to use `fmt`.

```
kwargs = {'format': '%.1f'}
cb = m.colorbar(cs, "bottom", size="3%", pad='2%', extend='neither', 
                drawedges=False, 
                norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=xaxis_min, vmax=xaxis_max),
                spacing='proportional', **kwargs)
```

Comment: actually a scalebar, from a mapping perspective, for a projection like that, is totally useless since it is not applicable everywhere on the map.  It would be best to leave it out altogether.

Comment: @DanPatterson This isn't a scale bar... This is a colormap that is used to map a value  (say % below poverty for a given country) to a color representation. It is independent of the projection. The user's post demonstrates the use perfectly. Why the user chose to normalize the colors between `xaxis_min` and `xaxis_max` is another story.